# Image full height when width is 100%

Tags: css

I have an image at the top. I want it to be wide from left to right. Despite all kinds of change in the css settings, I can't get the full height of the image, but full width is working.

The size of the image is 1920 x 400 px, but when I measure the image, the height is only 345 px. Is it about proportions or what? I have tested to change the width of the image, but I still get the height of 345 px!

My questions are: Can I get full height of the image and what is the optimal size in width when using a wide image? I guess it's not necessary tp have 1920.

HTML:

```
<div id="start">
<img class="start" src="bilderGuide/bilderLayout/start.jpg" />
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#start
{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

img.start
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59zH6/1/)

I just set the css property's off the image to

```
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
```

So it fills the page.

Or isnt that what you mean?

**EDIT:**
[New jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59zH6/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want it to fill the page, just the as a slider in the top. I can set it to 400px, but then I get problem hen I want to resize it for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a 100% size in an element wrapped inside another, it can occupy it's parent size. The 100% width in this case, as it is an image, will take all #start available width and proportionally adjust it's height (at least in most browsers).

There are a few tricks you can use, depending on the result you want:

```
  #start {width:960px;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;}
  img.start {/*reset max-min height if any*/ max-height:none;max-width:none;}
```

Image, then, will use it's real height and get masked with the #start width, since any overflow is hidden.

The idea, in general, is to have a wrapper element of the image and then play with the image css attributes depending on the result you want.

As for the optimal size, I would guess even a smaller width (1600px or so) would be enough but it all depends on the result you want.

Edit:
For a standard height, full width image you may use:

```
   #start {width:100%;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;height:300px;}
   img.start {min-height:300px;min-width:100%}
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/x3YjZ/)

Edit 2:
To get a full width and full height image masked, you'll need to absolute - position the wrapper of the images.

```
 #start {width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;}
 img.start {min-height:100%;min-width:100%;}
```

[another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3YjZ/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working! Why use a width of 960px, when I want full width?

Comment: Maybe I didn't really get what you asked for, the result you want is full width but images original height? full width and a fixed height?

Comment: Yes, but I can't use a fixed height of 400px, because then it don't work when I resize the browser to check how it will look on smaller devices.

Comment: So what exactly is the result you want to achieve? would 100% and 30% height be ok? the layout decision is totally up to you.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is when I use a height of 100% I don't get the full height of the image that is 400px

Comment: Not working! It will not be responsive design! Check out your jsfiddle example by resizing the brower. Image don't resize like the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#start {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
img.start {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
}
```